# Best way to find an element in Automation testing with selenium and Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to Automation testing with Selenium. For loading an element in DOM I am waiting upto 5 secs
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('my-id')), 5000).click();
But apparently, it works locally and sometimes fails on jenkins. Is there a better way to do this implementation without increasing the timeout?

Comment: We obviously need to see the web site / page you are working on to give you an answer to this question.

Comment: what is the error when it fails on the Jenkins ?

Comment: The error is:

element click intercepted: Element <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined certificates-toolbar-button MuiButton-outlinedPrimary Mui-disabled Mui-disabled" tabindex="-1" type="button" id="certificates-delete-btn" disabled="">...</button> is not clickable at point (948, 172). Other element would receive the click: <span title="" class="">...</span>   (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.97)

Comment: If you have `element click intercept` on Jenkins but it passes locally, your app is behaving differently from Jenkins. I would try adding a screenshot here to see if you can identify which element is intercepting the click, that will inform what you do from here.

Comment: There is something on top of that element, maybe a cookie /privacy modal dialog? or can you run it at the same resolution, the page layout may be different.